# Analysis in Division Rings

Tags: division-rings

In the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84306/what-are-other-applications-of-difference-equations-in-other-branches-of-mathemat), the subject of "Analysis in Positive Characteristic" is mentioned. Looking at Wikipedia's [local field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field), this is the final type of analysis in local fields to be developed following on from real, complex and p-adic analysis. ( Is there a snappy name for this? Charpos analysis ? ff/Fq analysis ? Carlitz analysis ?)

Question: What is the situation with regard to division rings - Is there a classification of local division rings? and for which ones has analysis been developed ?

Answer (score 4):

The classification of locally compact (non necessarily commutative) fields is done in chapter 1 of André Weil's Basic Number Theory. His method is very nice, based on the existence of a Haar measure on a locally compact group.

Comment: For a more concrete approach to the classification of (nondiscrete) locally compact division rings, see Jacobson, Basic Algebra II. 